# '1D target tensor expected' error when using pytorch tensorDataset class

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am wondering why this error is occuring. My hunch tells me that the tensorDataset reads the last column as being the labels, but I don't know why it would behave that way if I input a separate dataset for labels as the second argument. Also, can someone explain exactly how one-hot encoding works and how I can fix this problem because I only want one label per item?

```
Error: return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

inputs_file = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
targets_file = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')

inputs = inputs_file.iloc[1:1001].values
targets = targets_file.iloc[1:1001].values

inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32)
targets = torch.tensor(targets)

dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)

val_size = 200
test_size = 100
train_size = len(dataset) - (val_size + test_size)

# Divide dataset into 3 unique random subsets
training_data, validation_data, test_data = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])

batch_size = 50

train_loader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
valid_loader = DataLoader(validation_data, batch_size*2, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
```

Comment: What is the shape of `targets` in your code?

Comment: targets.shape = (999, 1)
inputs.shape = (999, 11)

Comment: Try `targets = targets.squeeze(1)` before creating the tensor dataset.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (11x1 and 11x8)
I should also add that I am using a hidden layer of size 8 and i have 5 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from the comments discussion, the error is reproduced by the following.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset, random_split

inputs = torch.randn(999, 11, dtype=torch.float32)
targets = torch.randint(5, (999, 1), dtype=torch.long)

# you need this to adapt from pandas, but not for this example code
# inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, dtype=torch.float32)
# targets = torch.tensor(targets)

dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)

val_size = 200
test_size = 100
train_size = len(dataset) - (val_size + test_size)

# Divide dataset into 3 unique random subsets
training_data, validation_data, test_data = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size, test_size])

batch_size = 50

train_loader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
valid_loader = DataLoader(validation_data, batch_size*2, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

# guess model. More on this in a moment
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(11, 8),
    nn.Linear(8, 5),
)

loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for features, labels in train_loader:
    out = model(features)
    loss = loss_func(out, labels)
    print(f"{loss = }")
    break
```

#### Solution 1

Add `labels.squeeze(-1)` to the loop body a la

```py
for features, labels in train_loader:
    out = model(features)
    labels = labels.squeeze()
    loss = loss_func(out, labels)
    print(f"{loss = }")
    break
```

#### Solution 2

Flatten your targets initially with

```
targets = torch.tensor(targets[:, 0])
```

---

In response to

> Now I am getting this error: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (11x1 and 11x8) I should also add that I am using a hidden layer of size 8 and i have 5 classes

My architecture is a *guess* at what you're using, but as the code above is resolved by the target reshape, I'll need more to be more helpful.

Perhaps some documentation to assist? [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) The example code shows the expected shape of the targets being `N`, rather than `N, 1` or `N, classes`.